# To show the equivalence of two statements related to $B^n_2 \subset K \subset dB^n_2$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, convex-geometry

> Consider the polytope $$K = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \langle x,v_i\rangle \leq 1, 1\le i\leq m\}$$ with $m$ facets, for which $$B^n_2 \subset K \subset dB^n_2$$ where $1<d\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $B^n_2 := \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \| x\| \leq 1\}$, i.e. the Euclidean ball of unit radius. $dB^n_2$ is the scaled version of this.

**What I have so far:**

- The first inclusion implies that each $\|v_i\| \leq 1$ for all $1\leq i\leq m$ (since $\frac{v_i}{\|v_i\|} \in B^n_2$).
- The second inclusion gives us that if $\|x\| > d$ $(x\notin dB^n_2)$, then there exists $i$ such that $\langle x,v_i\rangle > 1$ (so that $x\notin K$).

**What I want to show:**
I want to show that the second conclusion above is **equivalent to**:
For every unit vector $\theta$, there exists an $i$ such that $$\langle \theta,v_i\rangle \geq \frac{1}{d}$$

How should I go about this? I'm unable to relate the statements I have so far to *unit vectors* in any sense - and hence I haven't had much progress proving the above equivalence. I tried starting off with $\langle d\theta,v_i\rangle \geq 1$ instead, so that $\|d\theta\| = d$ and $d\theta\in dB^n_2$.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

---

*Clarification:*

- $d\theta$ = $d \times \theta$, i.e. $d$ times the unit vector $\theta$. It is not the infinitesimal $d\theta$ seen often in analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part are you struggling with?

The backward direction follows immediately, since for any $x$ with $\|x\|>d$, you know that there exists some $i$ such that $\left\langle \frac{x}{\|x\|},v_i\right\rangle \geq \frac{1}{d}$. Multiplying this by $\|x\|$ on either side gives the required.

For the forward direction, for any $d'>d$, you know that there exists $i$ such that $\langle \theta,v_i\rangle>\frac{1}{d'}$. Are you able to conclude from here that there exists $i$ such that $\langle \theta,v_i\rangle\geq\frac{1}{d}$?

Comment: $d' > d \implies \frac{1}{d'} < \frac{1}{d}$ so $\langle\theta,v_i\rangle > \frac{1}{d'} < \frac{1}{d}$. Nothing conclusive here, what am I missing?

Comment: Suppose instead that for every $i$, $\langle\theta,v_i\rangle < \frac{1}{d}$. Since the set of these values is finite, it must have a _maximum_ that is also less than $\frac{1}{d}$, say some $\frac{1}{d'}$. This is clearly a contradiction since you know that there exists some $i$ such that $\langle\theta,v_i\rangle>\frac{1}{d'}$.

Comment: Well written, thanks!

Comment: Since you have gone through Prof. Keith Ball's notes, I am asking an unrelated follow-up question (hope you won't mind): After establishing the above equivalence, the author goes on to say that we must minimize $m$, such that $v_i$'s satisfy $\|v_i\| \le 1$ and $\forall\theta\exists i (\langle\theta,v_i\rangle \geq 1/d)$. Then, it is said that **we cannot do better than look for vectors $v_i$ of length exactly $1$.** - why is that? Also why does this imply that our polytope touches the ball? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Note that if $(v_i)$ is a set of vectors that satisfies the conditions, then the set $(v_i/\|v_i\|)$ satisfies the conditions as well (Why?). Hopefully, it is clear from this that you can assume that all the $(v_i)$ are of unit norm. For your second question, you can describe the polytope as the intersection of the half-spaces (containing $0$) formed by the hyperplane at each $v_i$ that is orthogonal to it (each constraint in the definition corresponds to a half-space). Each of these planes touches the ball. Try visualizing this in three dimensions to better understand.

Comment: Which ball is this? $B^n_2$ or $dB^n_2$? or both?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine The former, you're just replacing the first condition with an equivalent one.